# Vue 3 inertia not resolving components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs

I am trying to dynamically resolve components in an inertia app, but it doesn't work.

```
console.log(import.meta.glob('../views/pages/*.vue'));
function resolving(name) {
  let u = withVite(import.meta.glob('../views/pages/*.vue'), name);
  console.log(`WTF ${name}`, u);
  return u;
}

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => resolving(name), // withVite(import.meta.glob('../views/pages/*.vue'), name),
  setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

It seems `Votes` is never fetched. What could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `resolve: name => resolving(name)` is not looking for components in pages. You have to manual import each components in your views.

```
<template>
   <SomeComponent/>
</template>
<script setup>
import SomeComponent from '@/pages/some-component'
</script>
```

However if you want to automatize this process, you can use `unplugin-vue-components`. If you are using `vite` you have to modify `vite.config.ts` with:

```
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    ...
    Components({ dts: true, dirs: [_path + "/views"], }),
  ]
})
```

Then you don't need the `import SomeComponent from '@/pages/some-component'` anymore.